# knockoutjs get element id through click event

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm using knockoutjs and I currently have something in my view that looks like this:

```
<img id="myTab1" data-bind="click: pressedTab.bind($data, '#myTab1')" src="images/image1.png"></img>
```

This allows me to get the element ID in my view model:

```
pressedTab = function(tab){
    console.log("Element ID: " + tab);
}
```

This writes:

> Element ID: #myTab1

However, it's too repetitive to send the name of the img id in the click event. Is there a way to send the img id without explicitly re-writing it?

Comment: Below link works for me with knockout binding

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513689/knockout-to-get-the-attribute-value-onclick-function/31514589#31514589

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You actually can get access to the event object via a KO click handler.

```
<button id="somebutton" data-bind="click: log">Click Me </button>

var ViewModel = function() {
    this.log = function(data, event) {
        console.log("you clicked " + event.target.id);
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/e8JPT/

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will not be safe if there is icon on button something like this, `<button id="somebutton" data-bind="click: log"><span class='fa fa-user'></span>Click Me </button>`

Answer (score 13):

The answer of madcapnmckay is not completely correct. You can better use currentTarget: it will return the original bound element instead of a child element, when i.e. you have a div with nested elements in it.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101548/knockoutjs-get-the-real-bound-element-through-click-event)

**Update**

As @Ryan mentioned - event.currentTarget is not available for IE8. For <= IE8 support you can use:

```
var target = (event.currentTarget) ? event.currentTarget : event.srcElement;
```

Comment: I agree. vm.yourFn = function (data, event) {
      var $target = $(event.currentTarget) ... works great.

Comment: Please note that if you need to support IE < 9, currentTarget is not available for those versions.