# knockoutjs get the (real bound) element through click event

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158045/knockoutjs-get-element-id-through-click-event/14096449). Except that the answer returns the child element when a child element is clicked, i.e. in the case that you bind a div.

```
<div id="parent" data-bind="click: log">Parent Div<div id="child">Child</div></div>

<script>
    var ViewModel = function() {
        this.log = function(data, event) {
            console.log("you clicked " + event.target.id);
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
</script>
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8JPT/36/)

I want to get the original element the click event was bound to. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the code in fiddle works as you want it.. does it not ?

Comment: @Stefanos: He's looking for a way to get the parent element even if the click occurs within a child element. I.e. the element the binding was applied to.

Comment: This is a KO antipattern

Comment: hmm... you're right actually. But for the moment this is the quickest way. I'll refactor later.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`event.currentTarget` will give you the element to which the event is bound. Change your Console.log as below:

```
console.log("you clicked " + event.currentTarget.id);
```

Comment: event.currentTarget is not available for IE8. For <= IE8 support you can use:

`var target = (event.currentTarget) ? event.currentTarget : event.srcElement;`

Comment: @ShitalShah: It's more complicated than that. `srcElement` is more equivalent to `target` (the *originating* element, which may be a descendant) than like `currentTarget`. So when handling delegated clicks, there's an important difference.

Comment: I would like to add that if you console.log() out just the event in bind loop, currentTarget will be null - don't be confused, it's just because it is not currentTarget AFTER the event has passed, it is available only in listener - while event is "active" :)