# Knockout to get the Attribute Value onClick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

HTML View with attr Value 'Qref'.

[image]

This is the HTML Code for bindling

Currently i have hard coded the Qref Attribute vaue

```
<!--ko if:$parent.Type == 2 -->
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr:{id: $data.Id , Qref: '3177'} , click: $root.answerClick">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span data-bind="text: $data.Text , attr:{id: $data.Id}"></span>
<!--ko if:$data.InputType == "text" -->
<input type="text">
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

This is the event for CLick.I am able to access the ID But not able to access the Qref Value.I want to know how can i access the Qref Value.

```
    answerClick: function (data ,event) {
                    var click_id = event.target.id;
                    return true;
                },
```

Comment: Presumably the `qref` value is going to be driven by your data model at some point?  If that's the case, leave it as a property in your viewmodel rather than inserting it into an attribute, and just use the `data` parameter in your `click` handler to access it.

Comment: you can simply send `click: function() {return $root.answerClick($data.yourBinding())}` or use `.bind($data,$data.yourBinding())` cheers

Comment: Can you show me the sample code in my answerclick function. I didn't got what you meant to say .

Comment: It's hard to say whilst `qref` remains hard coded.  Could you supply what your view model will actually look like?

Comment: I want to access Qref value . I can able to access id value by answerClick: function (data ,event) {
                    var click_id = event.target.id;
                    return true;                                                          
                },                                                              I have binded both id and qref in attr property. event.target.id give me a id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access attribute values of a DOM using the [`getAttribute`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp) function.

This will work for you:

```
answerClick: function(c, event){
        var element = event.target;
        var qref = element.getAttribute('Qref');
        var click_id = element.id;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Whilst this may work, it's not really the "knockout way" of doing things.

Comment: It certainly isn't the knockout way. It's difficult to gauge OP's situation and context from the information he has given. It does seem OP is quite far down the rabbit hole of doing things the non ko way.

Comment: No problem buddy, glad I could help : )

Comment: @JamesThorpe I totally agree with you on the approach isn't ko best practice. I think delving into the SPA/Knockout/Data Binding best practices and design would be better suited on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Perhaps.  If we'd known where `qref` was going to be coming from, rather than hard coded, we could have provided a better answer here too though.