# Set "title" of selected value from dropdown after selection using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, title, knockout-mvc

I am using knockout js with ASP.NET MVC. I want to show the selected value's text on title when user hover on the selected value after selecting on the dropdown. So if bigger value hidden goes can show in title.
like: if I have three values One, Two , BiggerValuethathidden.

So now obviously if my dropdown size is not that much bigger like third value, my third value will go hidden after size defined for dropdownlist.So I want to show when set value as title on hover.

Now I have try to implement the dropdownlist bind like this:

```
  <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: Accounts, optionsCaption: ' -- ', optionsText: function (item) { return item.AccountName }, optionsValue: function (item) { return item.Id }, value:AccountId, click: setTitle" required="required" data-parsley-required-message="Account is required" id="ddlAccounts">
```

To Set after so many searches , I am trying to do it like this:

```
<div title="" id=dvAccount">
      <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: Accounts, optionsCaption: ' -- ', optionsText: function (item) { return item.AccountName }, optionsValue: function (item) { return item.Id }, value:AccountId, click: setTitle" required="required" data-parsley-required-message="Account is required" id="ddlAccounts">
</div>
```

click event function based on [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513689/knockout-to-get-the-attribute-value-onclick-function):

```
setTip = function(c, event){
            var element = event.currentTarget;
            var qref = element.getAttribute('Qref');
            var click_id = element.id;
            return true;
        }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Please some one help me to do this tricky trick!

Answer (score 1):

You can use "attr" binding ("attr: { title: AccountId }" - you can put another (human-readable) value instead of AccountId):

```
<div data-bind="attr: { title: AccountId }" id=dvAccount">
      <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: Accounts, optionsCaption: ' -- ', optionsText: function (item) { return item.AccountName }, optionsValue: function (item) { return item.Id }, value:AccountId, click: setTitle" required="required" data-parsley-required-message="Account is required" id="ddlAccounts">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply I am trying it but AccountId is the Id. I want to show the text of it.

Comment: I don't know the structure of your view model, and I've wrote that you can use instead of "AccountId" the name of another human-readable field...

Comment: You mean to say I can set text like I have set value and use that variable instead of AccountId, right!

Comment: Yes, your view model has field "AccountId" and this field contains ID of the selected account. You need to add another field, that will return readable title for selected account.

Answer (score 0):

Uffffff it is accidently or I don't know but from last 3 questions I asked question and me myself post my answer, this time again.

I found an extreme helpful solution for title of dropdown selected value:

Just use this jquery and css combination:

```
$('select').each(function(){
            var tooltip = $(this).tooltip({
                selector: 'data-toggle="tooltip"',
                trigger: 'manual'
            });
            var selection = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
            tooltip.attr('title', selection)

            $('select').change(function() {
                var selection = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
                tooltip.attr('title', selection)
            });
        });
```

Thanks to TSV for such faster response and help me but this one is better as per my application.